# Highcharts context menu button appearing thrice for the same chart

Tags: highcharts

I am creating a highcharts. But when the chart finishes loading, i can see 3 buttons for context menu and only one of them functional. Please look at the image:[image]

I have just included these script tags in the html:

src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"

src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"

Comment: Ok, but what is your code ? The code who generate this chart ?

Comment: nothin unusual with the code pierre. Tried to paste the code here.. but it says too long... In the code im just creating the chart from json data and rendering it to the container. I have done nothing specific to the context menu. Am i missing something?

Comment: Past your code in a tool like pastie.org and give us the link it would be a lot easier for us to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Please find my code here:
http://pastie.org/8109842

Comment: And you have the three buttons right after clicking on the button `#Button1` or after many clicks ?

Comment: after a single click. When the chart loads, i see those three buttons on the top right.

Comment: Could you reproduce your problem in jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: I didn't reproduced the problem in JsFiddle. Which version of Highcharts do you use ?

Comment: Highcharts JS v3.0.2. I couldn't reproduce the problem in jsFiddle either

Comment: And your jQuery version ?

Comment: Still not reproducing... Do you have some options for highcharts you predifined before the code you gave us ?

Comment: No Pierre. I didnt define any options.

Comment: Do you any errors in the console ?

Comment: No errors Pierre. The chart comes up alright. If i remove the exporting module script tag, then the chart looks fine without the context menu. But i really need this context menu on the charts.

Comment: Can you link the fiddle you make to test your chart ? Cause I don't have the same style as your screenshot...

Comment: I reproduced your problem by changing the style of my chart. I post an answer on how I solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add the exporting options :

```
var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        // ...
    },
    exporting: {
        buttons: {
            contextButtons: {
                enabled: false,
                menuItems: null
            }
        },
        enabled: true
    },
    // ...
```

to your charts options. It seems that it could resolved your problem.

EDIT : I just editing the code, try it.