# multiple Export button in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

My problem is exactly the same as 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470797/highcharts-context-menu-button-appearing-thrice-for-the-same-chart)

but the solution is not working in my case.
as i m adding data at runtime appending 1 by 1 lines in highstock so m getting multiple buttons
please suggest how can i remove this multiple display.

Comment: That question doesn't really provide any good example code of how this problem occurs. Do you have code to replicate the problem? JSFiddle?

Comment: no i dnt have and i cnt show the code.its simple when i apend data it increase frst time its 1 next time it increase by 3

Comment: If its simple to do it should be simple to recreate as well. How do you add data?

Comment: i have data when i onclick on it it goes to a method call json with jquery and add data and create options for that and add series options in loop till last series option is added after that it makes other options and create the chart

Comment: The problem is that without code, even if I am able to recreate two export buttons, I have no idea if that is the same reason it occured to you, so I'm just left guessing about the reason and solution.